# Driving high power direction indicator LED

Tags: microcontroller, pcb-design, led-driver, high-current

I am using a direction indicator LED "2BA 013 398-03" from Hella for our robot. The system power is 24 V. The main microcontroller that also controls the LED on/off, can not provide the required current for the LED. I am trying to drive the LED to supply the required current. The problem is that when I connect the LED to the driver PCB the lighting is blinking and the voltage is fluctuating then after a while it settles at the minimum voltage of the LED but also the lighting is dull.

How can I drive without this blinking issue and no dropping to minimum voltage?

I tried the following driver for 200 mA setting.

- STCS05DR from STMicroelectronics (left pic)
- A6260KLJTR-T from Allegro MicroSystems (right pic)

[image: left is STCS05DR driver and right is A6260KLJTR-T driver]

Comment: Hello and welcome.  Are you simply turning the LED assembly fully on and off (I believe that's all it can do, and has integrated electronics).  If so, have you considered a MOSFET switch for the LED?

Comment: Hello, yes only on and off no more functionality. I tried with the MOSFET switch and it is working but I want to have some safety and protection options that these drivers can offer like short/open circuit and failure protection for example. I am confused about where can be the issue in the circuit.

Comment: An automotive indicator is likely to have a lot of circuit protection in it.

Comment: Are you certain your PSU is able to supply what you need?

Comment: the LED was supplied from the microcontroller but since it can't provide the required current, I tried to use a MOSFET switch controlled from the microcontroller, and the led is supplied directly from the battery. this worked out. but since it is from the battery I wanted to have a proper PCB and have like driver as mentioned above then this issue happened.

Comment: I mean are you sure your battery can supply the current required.

Comment: yes, sure it is. it is a high-power and high-capacity lithium battery, and it worked when I directly supplied the LED from the battery with the switch controlled by the microcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to drive an automotive indicator with a constant current drive, as if it was simply an LED needing a certain current.  It's designed to work the same as all the other indicators on a car: ie, it's effectively a circuit and some LEDs pretending to be just a light bulb.

Your Hella automotive indicator already has circuitry inside it to deal with constant current and other LED issues.  (Some, for example, will light a single LED if there isn't enough current.)

The indicator will use a different amount of power at different moments (it flashes).  This will cause your constant current drive to move the voltage up and down.

Your solution is to use any plain switch (MOSFET, relay) or a constant *voltage* driver, though there's no particular need for regulation.  If you want to sense that it's working, consider photodiode (is it lit?) or voltage.  In practice, an LED-based automotive lighting fixture is likely to be very reliable, perhaps more than other parts of your system.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fk6vov.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

Your two chips are both constant current regulators for driving LEDs directly:

- [STCS05DR](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/9f/32/57/ab/db/38/46/eb/CD00172756.pdf/files/CD00172756.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00172756.pdf) is 0.5 A Constant Current LED Driver
- [A6260](https://www.allegromicro.com/%7E/media/Files/Datasheets/A6260-Datasheet.ashx) is High Brightness LED Current Regulator

Comment: In that case wouldn't it rather be designed to work with raw 12V/24V battery voltage? If the circuitry inside is designed to give constant current, then there's no need to provide constant voltage.

Comment: @Lundin yes, automotive products generally are very tolerant on their voltage, and I agree there's no pretting need to provide regulation.  It won't hurt though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, then I will go with 2N2222A as a switch and IC 7805 to regulate 24v to 5v for the switch.

Comment: @OmarEfeoglu Any particular reason why you are using such components from the 1980s? Is this some garage project or a real product?

Comment: @OmarEfeoglu I'm not sure what the regulator would be for.  You might consider any of the basic drivers (mosfet probably best) shown in NYU's [lab exercise](https://itp.nyu.edu/physcomp/labs/motors-and-transistors/using-a-transistor-to-control-high-current-loads-with-an-arduino/).

Comment: @Lundin it is a real product but I am in the prototype and test phase and using what I have in the lab. no other reason. I would appreciate any product suggestions if you would like to share!

Comment: @OmarEfeoglu Switching buck regulators is what's used on the market today. My personal preference is anything from Analog Devices/LT. Been using LT's products for as long as I've worked in electronics and always with good experience & great customer support.

Comment: @Lundin as far as I understand it, the load is a 24V device being driven from a 24V battery, which I'd imagine we switch with a mosfet; could you clarify where you understand the buck regulator should go?

Comment: @jonathanjo According to OP: "and IC 7805 to regulate 24v to 5v for the switch". Not quite sure which switch they are talking about though. But I'm very sure that using 7805 from 24V to 5V regulation is the wrong solution in the vast majority of modern products.

Comment: @Lundin oh for certain, 7805 isn't going to help anything.  I added a diagram to be quite concrete about what I understand the solution to be.

Comment: The Regulator is only to provide the gate voltage. but I will look for 24v switch directly

Comment: Why do you need a regulator for the gate voltage, can't you take it directly from the MCU?

Comment: MCU gives 24V control signal

Comment: What kind of MCU is that?  Also, there are lots of ways of triggering MOSFETs

Comment: It is special for motors. It is provided with the motors I am using (Like the motor company provides both motor and controller). This is a high-power application with big motors. how would you suggest an efficient way to trigger

Comment: Have a look at this "mosfet gate clamping" with zener to restrict the voltage on the gate to whatever is appropriate for your mosfet.  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/422711